# How to change a map style using mapbox in angular

Tags: angular, mapbox

I am new to using angular,. I am not sure how to get the style of the map to change. I was able to create a button to allow the user to change the layer but I am unsure of how to add a click event listener to the button in angular.

Comment: Question should be more like "How to add click listener to button"

Answer (score 0):

*component.html*

```
<a (click)="myAction()">Click</a>
<div (click)="myAction()">Click</div>
<button (click)="myAction()">Click</button>
//...
```

*component.ts*

```
public myAction(){ //... }
```

[Angular Event Binding](https://angular.io/guide/event-binding)